# Efficient logging in JS

Tags: javascript, logging

Is there a way in js to make logging more efficient , without calling methods when not necessary
I would use Macros in C++ for this.

lets say I have a logger and I do 
log('Warning', 'this is the object' , JSON.parse(obj));

I dont want the JSON.parse to be called if the log level is below Warning.

Is there some way  a way around this
I had of thought of somehow encapsulating the function call by another and the logger calling the function inside to get the result but I think the overhead of creating an function each time is not worth it.
Any thoughts ?
Thanks.

Comment: The function is the way to do it. Creating functions is cheaper than parsing JSON. The function body is just parsed once, when the script is compiled; when you use it, it just has to make a closure with the variables.

Comment: myParse=debug?JSON.parse.bind(JSON):Boolean; then later:  log('Warning', 'this is the object' , myParse(obj));